# Sharepoint Services 3.0: 403 Forbidden fun

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-403, sharepoint-services

Can't get to the Administration or the "companyweb" site itself; was working up to a week ago.

Old threads, blog posts, etc. indicate that there was an issue with a KB update but was resolved when .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 was deployed/installed.

Running Process Monitor, I can see a lot of `PATH NOT FOUND','NAME NOT FOUND` for `c:\inetpub\companyweb\Default.aspx`, `\_themes\ice\...\foo.css`, etc. for the `w3wp.exe` process on `CreateFile`or`QueryOpen`operations.  These files do not exist in the location specified.

I don't recall these files actually existing in that folder, but I believe they're "created" when requested, pulled in from Common Files/Shared or whatever, in typically-awesome Microsoft Web architecture land (`</rant>`).

Besides reinstalling (which I'm sure will be as much fun as migrating from one server to another was), anyone know what's going on?

Google-fu has alluded me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving it to a new server: this new server has nothing else but SharePoint on it, so I (hopefully) won't run into any issues again, or at least can trace it back to a Windows Update.